# Get maximum height of window (browser) whether the browser is maximize or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get maximum height of window (browser) with JQuery in one of my website's forms,when browser is maximize I can get it's height and everything works fine,but the issue is when clients opens the website in a browser that is not maximize,in this case I also need the maximum height of browser,I searched for hours and tried below solutions,but none of them is not my answer :

```
window.innerHeight;
window.outerHeight;
window.screen.height;   
window.screen.availHeight;
$(document).height();   
document.body.clientHeight; 
document.body.offsetHeight; 
document.body.scrollHeight; 
document.documentElement.clientHeight;  
document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

for example,
the **screen height is 768px** and
**maximum browser height is 650px**

I need the **650px** whether the browser is maximize or not,but the closest value I can get from above solutions is **728px** that I can get it from **`window.screen.availHeight`**

how to get maximum height of window (browser) whether the browser is maximize or not with JQuery?
i appreciate any solution or idea,thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Dear Try creating a CSS file and add the following code:

```
.css({ "max-height": navHeight + 'px' });

.css({ "max-height": navHeight + 'px' });

.css("max-height", navHeight + 'px'));
```

you can set the maximum height of your own choice through this syntax